# Xcode doesn't show iPhone name

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5

I have strange problem.

I made app with deployment target of iOS 6.0

I have iPhone 4s with iOS 6.1 with XCode 4.5 installed on my Mac. XCode doesn't see my device. It says "iOS Device" not "krunal's iPhone" as usual.
(I am sure that device is connected because I see it in iTunes.) XCode denies to start my application on device. It says:

```
"The version of iOS on “krunal’s iPhone” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK"
```

**Please help..**

Comment: Don't you need Xcode **4.6** to support iOS 6.1?

Comment: Take organiser->see your device in left panel->see if it has a yellow dot or green dot next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to Xcode 4.6, which includes support for iOS 6.1.

Comment: If it resolves the question, it's fine to answer in this way. Simple questions get simple answers.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I don't get it: the problem, as indicated by the error message, is that the version of Xcode he is using doesn't support the version of iOS he is using.  The correct answer is to upgrade to a version of Xcode that does support the version of iOS he is using.  How is that "cheap" or "poor quality"?  It directly solves his problem in the most straightforward manner.

Comment: @trojanfoe, as for you leaving a comment to that effect a couple of minutes earlier, you should have left it as an answer.  Comments are for getting more information, not for answering.  If you have an answer that can solve his problem, post it as an answer next time.

Comment: Well I was just reacting to what I saw as a cheap steal of my comment.  It's not important and I'm not even convinced it will solve the issue.  I will remove my comments and downvote when the answer is next edited.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Organizer and Select your device and mark your device for development, this should do it.

Comment: Now in the bottom add your device to portal, and get a development certificate for the devise